# AngularJS use $location within a factory

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-resource

I created a factory which is using the $resource factory, I want to customise the url params passed to the $resource according my current URL.
here's my code sample:

```
MyApp.factory("provider_services", ['$resource', function($resource) {
  var factory = {};
  var ProviderService = $resource("/providers/:provider/provider_services/", { format: 'json', provider: "pro" });
  factory.services = ProviderService.query();

  return factory;
}])
```

My current url is:  somedomain.com/providers/**pro**/services/

I want to pull the "pro" part out of the url (that ideally can be anything else) and pass it in the provider param to the resource (in my current sample you can see it's hardcoded).
something like:

```
cur_provider = {get the current value from the url}
var ProviderService = $resource("/providers/:provider/provider_services/", { format: 'json', provider: cur_provider });
```

*I know I can do it using $location somehow, but I can't seem to access it within my provider_services factory.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use $routeParams to do this. It would look something like this:

```
angular.module('app').controller("ExampleController", ['$resource', '$routeParams', 'SomeService',
    function($resource, $routeParams, SomeService) {
        //The id here is whatever you name your route variable.
        cur_provider = $routeParams.provider;
        var ProviderService = $resource("/providers/:provider/provider_services/", { format: 'json', provider: cur_provider });
    }
]);
```

Comment: I can't get this part of the URL from the $routeParams as my angular app root is in somedomain.com/providers/pro/services. if the url was somedomain.com/providers/pro/services/caregory/test - I could have access the "test" with $routeParams.categoryName. Anyway, I'm trying to do it within my factory.

Comment: It doesn't matter where at in the URL the param is, the parameter in the URL is signified by the ":". Check out this link, they do a good job of explaining it: https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/routeparams-api

Comment: as I said, $routeParams don't know my entire URL, its relative to my angular root (which is 'somedomain.com/providers/pro/services'). once I'm in 'somedomain.com/providers/pro/services/caregory/test' I can see the category parameter but nothing else.